# Web Application behaviour different when publishing in Azure

Tags: c#, jquery, azure

I have created a web application in which I am calling c# method. In the c# method, I return an object that contains a value like 1, 2 , 3. When I run the application in the localhost, I get the exact value of the object. However, when I publish this application in AZURE without making any change. I don't get the value like 1, 2, 3 but instead I get the value System.Object. 
I don't understand this strange behaviour. Kindly assist me.
Here is my code:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    PageMethods.SaveNDig(obj, OnComplete);
});
```

C# Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveNDig(Object obj)//string CourseName, string CourseCategoryURL, string CourseCategoryName, string CourseInfo, string PassPercentage, string TextBooks, string GradingSchemes
{

    object result = database.ExecuteScalar("select userid from EUser where username ='" + username + "'");
    return result;
}

public static object ExecuteScalar(string query)
{
    object obj = new object();
    try
    {
        con = InitializeConnection();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return obj != null ? obj : null;
}
```

Comment: You could always not swallow your exceptions to see if there is a problem with your query `catch (Exception ex) { }` add some logging or remote debug it.

Comment: have you considered using Entity Framework?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar returns an Object. I have seen this issue that you are referring to -- and in fact, came across your question looking for issues with Azure and ExecuteScalar. ExecuteScalar is documented to return the first column in the first row of the returned object.

FYI, we use Entity Framework and the DB in question resides locally and in the cloud. Locally, my inserts work find using ExecuteScalar, but the Object returned is useless. Attempting to cast it throws an InvalidCast exception.

I have started replacing ExecuteScalar with ExecuteNonQuery and that works fine so far.

Here is an article that I found most helpful in troubleshooting my Azure based DB access…

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/05/31/3-tips-for-sql-azure-connection-perfection